# Looping and/or filterering through array with object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested-loops

Iḿ trying to run through an array with object to get different results as part of an excercise for our IT Bootcamp.
I just can´t seem to get it working. First here is the task.

```
Create an array of cars. The cars are objects and they have the properties: brand, price, horsepower, color and year_of_construction. Create following cars there: 
    * `BMW(70000, 200hp, white, 2020)`
    * `Mazda(45000, 220hp, silver, 2021)`
    * `Volvo(55000, 190hp, beige, 2021)`
    * `Opel(38000, 155hp, black, 2021)`
    * `Mazda(22000, 90hp, magenta, 2021)`
    * `Fiat(19000, 110hp, blue, 2019)`
* Create a loop which filters all cars which cost less than `60000` (means print all properties).
* Create a loop which filters all cars which have more than `150 hp`.
* Create a loop which will print all cars that are made after `2020` and have less than `100 hp`.
* Create a loop which will print all cars that are by `Fiat` or have less than `150 hp`.
```

Now my code, I can access different indexes in the array, but if I run the code with the loop at the end the console just says (0=)[].

Please help me, somerwhere I don´t get the logic

`

```
let cars = [
        {
            Brand: "BMW",
            price: 70000,
            horsePower: 200,
            color: "white",
            yearOfConstruction: 2020,
        },
        {
            Brand: "Mazda",
            price: 45000,
            horsePower: 220,
            color: "silver",
            yearOfConstruction: 2021,
        },
        {
            Brand: "Volvo",
            price: 55000,
            horsePower: 190,
            color: "beige",
            yearOfConstruction: 2021,
        },
        {
            Brand: "Opel",
            price: 38000,
            horsePower: 155,
            color: "black",
            yearOfConstruction: 2021,
        },
        {
            Brand: "Mazda",
            price: 22000,
            horsePower: 90,
            color: "magenta",
            yearOfConstruction: 2021,
        },
        {
            Brand: "Fiat",
            price: 19000,
            horsePower: 110,
            color: "blue",
            yearOfConstruction: 2019,
        },
    ];

    let newCars = [];
for (let i=1; i<= cars.lenght; i++){
    if (cars[i].price < 60000){
        newCars.push(cars[i]);
    }
}
console.log(newCars);
```

`

Thanks for your help.

I tried looking for a solution but we should just use loops and every solution I found uses functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here:

1. You need to start iterating from 0 rather than 1
2. You have a spelling error `cars.lenght` should be `cars.length`
3. As @wendt88 pointed out in the comments, it should be `< cars.length` not `<=`

I recommend you use a VS Code with the Code Spell extension - it will point out spelling errors for you.

FYI, you can also do this exercise using Array.prototype.filter:

```
const newCars = cars.filter(car => car.price < 60000)
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I changed the to mistakes but now I get an TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading `price`) Don´t know what that means.
If i use your suggestion with filter i get the following on my console:
(5) [{...},  {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}].

Comment: `i < cars.length`, not `<=`, so it could not find the last car to read it's property `price`

Answer (score 0):

```
let filter1 = cars.filter(car => car.price < 60000);
console.log(filter1);

let filter2 = cars.filter(car => car.horsePower > 150);
console.log(filter2)

let filter3 = cars.filter(car => car.yearOfConstruction > 20 && car.horsePower < 100);
console.log(filter3);

let filter4 = cars.filter(car => car.Brand === "Fiat" || car.horsePower < 150);
console.log(filter4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it still won´t work completly.
I get the numbers of cars but still have the same problem that nothing is shown
I will post the complete code again.

Comment: filter1.map(car => console.log(car.Brand));

Comment: you have the filtered array, now you can use map to log any value

Comment: Ajay K thanks so much,one last Question, how can I make the console give out the brands for each filter in on line, because now they all appear underneath each other and this is quit hard to read.
If I´m not mistaken i would need to use array.push right?

Comment: yes, you can create new empty array and then push car brand in that array and then use join method to log in one line

Comment: you can do this also ->
let arr = filter1.map(car => car.Brand);
console.log(arr.join(" "))